# How to read the app.config settings in ESRI ArcObjects ArcMap Add-In

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, .net, add-in, visual-studio

I am developing custom toolbar and buttons for ArcMap 10.1 utilizing VS2010 and ArcObjects SDE 10.1 extensions.
I put some application settings in the app.config file and I want to make them available in the runtime. 
When I execute

```
private static readonly string appSetting1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appSetting1 "];
```

the value is null.

When I execute

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

the value is

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\bin\ArcMap.exe.Config"

Should I put my application settings is the ArcMap.exe.Config in order make them available to the ArcMap 10.1 custom toolbar or there is another way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: There is not a way to reference settings in an app.config for your custom assembly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889377/how-to-read-app-config-from-another-assembly

Why do you need these settings in an app.config?  Do you expect the user to be changing them or are they more constants?

Comment: I was hoping to use the settings instead of hard-coding values in the .cs files. Things like illegal characters RegEx string; max number selected features allowed, etc. I have to recompile every time those change instead of changing just the app.config settings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need as assembly to have it's own config you directly load it using this .net code.

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "THE PATH TO THE CONFIG";
System.Configuration.Configuration cfg =
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

string thevalue=cfg.AppSettings.Settings[variable].Value;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx

Also you can look at these StackOverflow posts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545/get-the-app-config-of-another-exe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311253/config-files-for-assemblies-in-gac